# Have a prompt when a tag is created

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

When a tag is created, a prompt should be raised, just so that people know they they are creating a tag, and are doing it intentionally.

I think that should solve address the answers to my [previous question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3205/force-tag-wiki-creation-when-a-tag-is-created).

Comment: Is this something that will be implemented, or a bad idea...

Its hard to tell with no answers.

Comment: Upvotes suggest it's a good idea. Whether or not it's implemented is another

Comment: Is there a way to keep track of that?

Answer (score 1):

I hear what you're saying -- on Stack Overflow we keep raising the amount of reputation required to create tags.

I would rather do that than institute another "here is a dialog users will not read then rapidly click through" feature.

Can you either edit this request, or create a new request, asking that the amount of rep required to create a tag be increased on this site?

https://superuser.com/tools?s=1

Per this 10k tools page (scroll to the bottom), the last few new tags created were utf-16, css-regions, spywareblaster for example.

Comment: I very rarely mean to create a tag, but occasionally I create one by accident (changing the form of the word or something similar) and don't realize that I just created a tag. There are many times this happens (a quick look at the tag synonyms page shows many like this todo and to-do, window7 and windows-7, tutorial and tutorials). I doubt that this dialog will be seen often, and therefore rapidly clicked through.