# Usage of "external" tag - burninate?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

I just removed the [external](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external) tag from a question regarding viewing of source code for a browser, and it got me thinking that this is somewhat a meta-tag.

There exists tags such as [external-hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-hard-drive) and [external-display](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-display), and most current [external](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external) tagged questions are related to these or similar external devices.

The tag was also mentioned in the [Tag cleanup for January 2013](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5718/tag-cleanup-for-january-2013) post.

Should we burninate this tag?

## **UPDATE**

It is back, with 100 questions tagged for it. I suggest black-listing it as well

Comment: Looks useless to me as well

Comment: I vote we replace `external` with `burninate`. Pretty applicable for external CD/DVD-RW drives, IMO.

Comment: Fixed. No more tags.