# What is the tag "external" used for and what is "external-drive" used for?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-request, tag-synonyms

This might be a language problem, but aren't [external](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external) and [external-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-drive) two the same?

If not, could somebody please add a text to both of them?

Comment: [external] is a meta tag that's been used to refer to every imaginable type of external device or component.  The questions need tag cleanup.

Comment: See also: [Usage of “external” tag - burninate?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/6261/107240)

Answer (score 4):

As stated by fixer [external](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external) is a meta tag, meaning that it does nothing to clarify the problem except when used as a modifier for other tags. Tags should be clear, well defined and accurate rather than requiring a list of them to nail down the problem.

If a tag can be applied to almost anything then it is a good target for burnination.

A short list of the uses of  [external](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external):

- sites
- drives
- laptops [?!¡¿](https://superuser.com/questions/972824/how-to-close-the-lid-on-the-asus-zenbook-without-putting-it-to-sleep)
- displays (monitors) [*](https://superuser.com/questions/782227/probook-4540s-monitors)
- applications [*](https://superuser.com/questions/772874/externally-control-application-interface)
- flash drives [*](https://superuser.com/questions/754089/external-flash-lock)
- GPUs [*](https://superuser.com/questions/749903/external-gpu-for-macbook-mac-mini)

The list of abuses go on.

Preferably where possible questions should be tagged properly, but the most egregious abuses of [external](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external) should simply have the tag deleted.

Most obvious candidates for tags:

- [external-hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-hard-drive)
- [external-optical-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-optical-drive)