# Question about converting a multi-page PDF file to PNG files - can it be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request, software-rec

This is about my question: [How to convert a multi-page PDF file to PNG files, with one PNG file per page of the PDF document?](https://superuser.com/questions/243461/how-to-convert-a-multi-page-pdf-file-to-png-files-with-one-png-file-per-page-of) - which has been recently closed as off-topic for "seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations".

I've read the meta post, [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software), and the meta post, [Could we finally get rid of [software-rec]?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8505/could-we-finally-get-rid-of-software-rec/) (Note: My question didn't have the [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) tag since 2011 and was posted well before the Software Recs SE existed.) If I understood the top-voted answers in those meta posts correctly, my question was and still is on-topic.

Quoting the relevant part of the [the top-voted answer](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8505/10259) in the latter meta post.

> ...
>   Just because someone is asking for a tool to solve a problem, doesn't make it the kind of question we don't want.
>
> Semyon is explaining a very specific, niche problem, which he likes to
>   solve. He assumes that there would be a software that is the solution.
>   A question like that is perfectly valid for Super User.
>
> "What's your favorite text editor?" and "What tool can I use to
>   convert CommonMark to XPS?" are very different questions in our
>   software recommendation context.
>   ...
>
> Ultimately, we want to save every question we can. If it can be rewritten to suit our site, then it should.

I've edited out the "Is there a software…" part in the question body (it was never in the title), and made it be "How do I convert a multi-page PDF file to PNG files…", similar to the title.

Is my question still off-topic in its current state? If not, can it be reopened? If it's still off-topic, please mention how I can rewrite it to be on-topic.

Comment: @Ramhound It was closed when I posted this meta question. It has since been reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks okay to me.

It's sort of a spam magnet question and we need to make sure that we get rid of answers that don't explain anything but just say "Use this tool!". This is clearly what we want to avoid with questions that can be solved by simply using some piece of software.

One could also improve the accepted answer by giving a concrete example.