# I recommend tossing [hardware-rec]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

Subject says it all. Just posted a question and noticed the [hardware-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-rec) tag. This site specifically flags items on a regular basis that are hardware recommendations since they are too broad, so why have this tag?

And that said, I would recommend a review of anything that has [hardware-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-rec) happens so questions like that—which are pure hardware recommendations—can be ditched.

[image: Wall-E reviewing some hardware.]

Comment: Indeed, we shouldn't have tags for topics that are disallowed on the site.

Comment: Please read the tag description, which clearly explains when a question with this tag is on or off topic.

Comment: There is a Hardware Recommendations SE.  Should people be redirected there?

Comment: Related: [Could we finally get rid of [software-rec]?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8505/194694)

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I'd say yes. Is that just a matter of updating the tag description to point users to [hardwarerecs.se]?

Comment: @kasperd I just added info to the tag description regarding the Hardware Recommendations SE (pending review).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree philosophically, but as a practical matter, blatantly off-topic tags serve a useful function when they are subjects that will always be improperly posted here.

We will never stop hardware or software requests.  The same applies to a number of other subjects that are virtually always off-topic.  Having a tag that states that is useful (and it's likely to get recreated, anyway, if we delete it, unless it's blacklisted in all of its possible variations).

- Posters may read the wiki excerpt and not post the question here.  ROTFL; I crack me up!
- It makes spotting these questions much easier.  They stand out like a sore thumb on the main page, which means they get disposed of quickly.
- The wiki excerpt is something we can point to when advising the poster why their question is being closed (or migrated, depending on the subject & tag).
- It clarifies the intent of the question.  Occasionally, someone using these tags will have a problem that can be fixed natively, without recommending something they need to purchase.  But the tag generally indicates that the poster came here asking for a purchase recommendation, in which case they came to the wrong place.  That's a starting point for their interaction.

Comment: Agreed. Moreover the tag itself is not a reason why a person publishes such a post and removing it will not prevent such posts. People will use more general tags like `hardware` and it will become more difficult to track such posts.