# Blacklist request: [Move], [Removal] and some more

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, blacklist

following the [tag cleanup for march 2013](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5718/tag-cleanup-for-march-2013) I have cleaned up the [move](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/move) meta-tag. No more questions with move.

FYI, most of these questions referred to moving files - I have replaced these mostly with [file-transfer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-transfer) or [file-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-management). File-transfer seems rather generic, though, so it was not a satisfactory solution.

Most of the rest referred to moving windows or partitions. A few also to "moving house" or "moving computers around". Some could be used for migration to new computer.

Can we prevent the move-tag from being used again? (If I understand correctly, this is what "burnination" is for.)

EDIT: Why not blacklist a few tags at once? Here's a list of meta-tags that we should blacklist after cleaning up.

- [move](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/move)
- [removal](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/removal)
- [detection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/detection)
- [hide](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hide)
- [utility](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utility)

Comment: As I understand it, *burnination* is the act of removing the tag from all questions, while *blacklisting* is the act of preventing future use of a tag (and usually only done is relatively extreme cases). There's also tag synonyms, where one tag is mapped to another one.

Comment: Yeah, about time we get some tags blacklisted. All the cleanup is worth nothing if some users are tempted to use these tags again.

Comment: @slhck There are many other tags that can be blacklisted, like [move], for example [removal].

Comment: We could keep adding the cleaned-up tags from the Tag review here and blacklist them all at once where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I've removed and blacklisted [detection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/detection) and [removal](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/removal). The rest look at though they're being kept under control without the need for this.