# Highlight tags that have a planned tag-cleanup on Meta

Tags: feature-request, tags

This may be pie-in-the-sky, but it would be useful if there were some way to connect Meta [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) tag-cleanup posts to the related tags on the main Super User page.

For example, cleanup of [images](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/images) is discussed in [this meta post](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9149/girl-youre-a-mess-images-needs-a-makeover). The [images](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/images) tag wiki has been edited to warn users not to use the tag, yet I see it being misused on new posts all the time. Moreover, I see questions with this tag being edited but the tag is not replaced by the editor.

Tag wiki excerpts alone are not very effective at altering the tagging behavior of users, and I doubt that anyone follows Meta Super User closely enough to know which tags have been deprecated. There's a pretty clear disconnect here between what's happening on the site and what's being prescribed on Meta.

So what to do? To keep these tags from propagating and to aid the cleanup process, there needs to be a better way to flag users that a deprecated flag is being used. There was [a similar meta feature-request](https://meta.superuser.com/q/6851/76571) for applying a different color scheme to "invalid" tags. While the idea of "invalid" was at issue in the old rejected request, the color flag idea is well suited to this purpose. To be clear, this request is different; it would limit different coloration to tags with [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) tag-cleanup requests.

My suggestion is that the different coloration only appears when the question is being edited. That is, it only shows up on the edit page, not on the main page or the question page. This is a rough mock-up, but something like this would do:

[image]

This would hopefully draw the attention of the question writer or the editor and let them know that a deprecated tag has been used. There may need to be some verbal indication on the page as well to explain the appearance of the tag. Maybe the visual cue alone will lead to the editor mousing over the tag to see the warning in the tag wiki excerpt.

Is this something we're interested in? Is it useful? Can it be done a different, better way?

Comment: I'd only be interested if it had more freehand circles drawn ;). +1

Comment: Great idea, but I don't understand why you want to limit the display to the edit page.  If a new question shows up on the main page with a honking tag warning, it will get fixed, either by the OP or by someone else who sees the need to fix it.

Comment: @fixer1234 For aesthetic and (SE) philosophical reasons. I think if we colored the tags on the feed, the bad tags would really stand out and probably detract from everything else. Same goes for the question page itself. With respect to site design, I think it's important to keep in mind the primary purpose of the site. That is, this is a site for questions and answers. Editing and moderation are not a major part of most users' experience of the site, so it doesn't make much sense to show these editing cues to all visitors. Limiting it to the edit and ask pages keeps it unobtrusive and targeted