# Do we need the "used" and "user-friendly" tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Neither [used](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/used) nor [user-friendly](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-friendly) seem to be of much use to me.

And while we're at it, is [refurbished](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/refurbished) worth keeping?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to collect these tags in a sticky tag cleanup thread http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5718/tag-cleanup-for-july-2013?cb=1 than creating a new question for new tags? Anyway, these two tags are not useful and look like meta tags and I'd ask for burnination directly instead of discussing them.

Comment: @user99572isfine: I guess I could have included it there but thought a discussion might be in order, which is difficult in such a catch-all thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, none of the three tags were worth keeping.

I've manually cleaned up all the questions they were tagged with.

[image: mission accomplished. we out.]
<sub>(source: [qkme.me](http://i.qkme.me/3v8gmb.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Nicely done, although I thought some prior discussion was warranted else I'd simply have done it myself.