# Tag cleanup of closed questions

Tags: discussion, clean-up

While doing my bit for the current [Tag Cleanup](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5718/tag-cleanup-for-feb-march-2014) I notice several questions with deprecated tags that are closed.   [This](https://superuser.com/questions/476248/how-to-do-you-access-a-website-youtube-blocked-by-the-government-censor)  is just one example.

Given the advice about updating or migrating crap, which is good advice, should we remove tags from closed questions or leave the questions for deletion by those with the power?

I'm concerned about bringing closed questions back to the front page of the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say, do both.

Removing the obsolete tags is priority, but you can also flag it for deletion afterwards.

- If a mod agrees, the whole question will be removed (very likely for old, closed questions).
- If the mod doesn't agree, at least the tag is gone.