# Some tag edits cause a demand for body edits

Tags: bug, tags

Usually, when editing the tags on a question as part of a [tag cleanup](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5718/tag-cleanup-for-april-2014) simply editing the tag is accepted by the system.

Most recently: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/676109/last-interactive-logon-only-for-one-user) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/689974/sleep-button-is-not-active-in-windows-7-ultimate)

Occasionally, a popup appears demanding 6 characters of change in the body of the question.

Most recently:
[here](https://superuser.com/questions/737814/how-to-use-healthy-primary-partition)

Is there something in some questions that causes this popup to occur?  I haven't seen any pattern.  Could it be a bug?

Comment: links to these questions?

Comment: Sorry, should have included them - edited in the most recent occasions now.

Comment: Here's another one that fails: http://superuser.com/questions/361721/my-copy-paste-no-longer-works-on-my-laptop

Comment: Same problem. I'm trying to change asp-classic to asp.net tag, have not touched the body, and a 6 char edit is being demanded: here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26561986/edit