# The msi tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Currently we have the [msi](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msi) tag which (according to the description) is supposed to be used for tagging questions about Windows `.msi` installer files. However, there are quite a few questions (about a third) where people have used the tag because they are asking about issues relating to [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-Star_International) hardware. Most of the questions about MSI hardware are a few years old so I'm guessing the tag's description was edited at some point.

My thought is that maybe we should have an [msi](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msi) tag for questions about MSI products and a tag called [msi-file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msi-file) or [msi-installer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msi-installer) or something similar for questions about MSI installers? Or we could just remove the msi tag from the questions about hardware.

Comment: Related: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3948/company-tag-necromancy-the-zombie-apocalypse/5648#5648 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags

Comment: Even if we do not need a new [msi] tag for tagging questions about MSI products, I still think the current tag needs a better name since people casually typing msi into the tags textbox could be using it incorrectly without even realising.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Questions referring to the Windows Installer packages (`.msi` files) should be tagged [windows-installer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-installer).

The tag [msi](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msi) should be merged (and synonymized) into [windows-installer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-installer) as company tags aren't very helpful and people will use the tag to refer to Windows Installer packages anyway.

Comment: Over the last couple of days I've suggested edits on all uses of [msi]-the-company (there's only a couple left pending) - once they're cleared you should be right to synonymise [msi] with [windows-installer] :)

Comment: @Robotnik: Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [msi-installer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msi-installer) (could be [ms-msi-installer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-msi-installer) too) and merge also [windows-installer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-installer) which excerpt also says that means the same thing.

Summary:

- Rename [msi](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msi) to [msi-installer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msi-installer) (or any other unambigous)
- Merge [windows-installer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-installer) into the first.
- Let both original tags die and see if they appear again.