# Reverse the [vlc] synonym direction?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

Currently, [vlc-media-player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vlc-media-player) is synonymised to [vlc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vlc). I think it would be better the other way around.

Doing so, we would:

- Reduce the ambiguity of the tag. It would then be obvious, even to people who've never heard of VLC that VLC is a media player.
- Future-proof against other things using the acronym 'vlc'. (Just like what happened with the [msi tag](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8166/the-msi-tag-is-ambiguous))
- Use the full (correct) name, rather than an abbreviation.

Thoughts?

Comment: Good idea. I keep getting VLC and VNC mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I meant to do it earlier, slipped out of my mind. This is now done.

```
updating post history, 925 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 764 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [vlc-media-player] and [vlc] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
30 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```