# Potential Tag Merge/Synonym: [msiexec] -> [windows-installer]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[msiexec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msiexec) is used by 7 questions to denote `msiexec.exe`, which is the actual executable of Microsoft's Windows Installer program.

Seeing as we already have a tag for [windows-installer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-installer), and the fact that [msi](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msi) is already a synonym* of it, this tag should probably be merged (and potentially synonymised) with [windows-installer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-installer).

Thoughts?

<sub>* see [here](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8166/107240) and [here](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8402/107240) for why msi is a synonym and doesn't represent the company MSI.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As above [msiexec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msiexec) has been merged into [windows-installer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-installer) and a synonym created.

Answer (score 6):

Agreed. Since the [msiexec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msiexec) tags should have [windows-installer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-installer) tags in any case, I've gone ahead and started tagging them as such too.

Comment: Please stop adding redundant tags.  If these are merged or synonomized, this will create additional cleanup.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually I guess this leads me to another question: Why not just remove the msiexec tag from those questions and add windows-installer?

Comment: Synonomizing or merging eliminates the need for any of those changes, or bumping old questions with edits.

Comment: Got it. In a case when there is 6 questions in the tag and there hasn't been a new one in over a year, I wonder if it isn't easier to just retag them. Sorry for jumping the gun there though.